# Showing a ggplot graph on a Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, ggplot2, shinydashboard

I'm creating a dashboard using Shiny Dashboard in R. However, a few times I have tried to add graphs to the dashboard and received an error like this:

> Error : cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'

This happens when I've created a graph using ggplot2, and am trying to use it in the dashboard - for example, see the code below, where newplot is the graph I've created (I've also tried putting it in "quotation marks"). I've also tried to add social media information using the twitteR package, which gets the same error. Both of these things show as I want them to outside the dashboard environment, but either get an error message or show a blank inside.

So am I trying to do something that can't be done (if so, is there a different package I should be using?) - or am I just not writing the code correctly to pull in the visuals I want?

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Relevant information", titleWidth = 350),
  dashboardSidebar(
    width = 350,
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Number", tabName = "number", icon = icon("user")),
      menuItem("Other", tabName = "other", icon = icon("users"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "number",
    fluidRow(
      box(plotOutput(newplot, height = 250)),
      )
    ),
  tabItem(tabName = "other",
          h2("Other stuff")
       )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: May we see the server code where the plot is created?

Comment: The first argument to `plotOutput` is the name of the output variable holding the plot.  It looks like your `newplot` is something else.

Comment: So potentially, rather than using the object that I've already created, I should create the plot within the plotOutput code? I'm not sure what kind of object the plot created using ggplot2 is.